# Weird behavior with margin on mac when opacity of child element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, macos

I am building a memory game. It works fine on chrome on Windows.

However with a mac, there is a weird glitch, that causes the cards to jump after the second set of cards gets uncovered.

The code for each card is this:

```
<div id="'+counter+'" class="'+num+' card covered"><div>'+num+'</div></div>
```

whereas counter is the int variable from a for loop, num is the face of the card (a random number, making sure it has only 1 pair per number).

The cards get covered or uncovered by a change in the background color of our `.card` and the opacity of the child element `.card div` gets set to 1 or 0 respectively.
Also the cards were rotated and spaced randomly via jquery.

Here are two fiddles:
http://jsfiddle.net/awm0ccbp/7/

Click on each card to uncover it. It should work fine.
Basically what it does is every time you click on a card change the opacity of the child element from 0 to 1.

Here is the second version:
http://jsfiddle.net/awm0ccbp/6/
This time the cards get covered again after you uncovered 2 cards.Starting on the third click, things will get messy: The previously uncovered cards get flipped over (opacity back to 0) but the newly uncovered card will somehow get an additional margin, causing all the cards to be pushed around.

I believe the margin comes from our child element, which is rotated, and therefore pushes cards over and to the side.

So why does it act so weird on a mac, after you cover the cards back up?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work on a Mac, I'm assuming you mean the Safari browser because that's where I saw the problem.

Comment: It is a problem on both safari and chrome on mac, but it works on chrome on windows. AFAIK they both use the same WebKit rendering engine...!? Your answer sounds promising, will try it as soon as i have access to that mac again! Thanks

Comment: were you able to try it out?

Comment: I was going to yesterday but i am sick... Next tuesday! Sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `font-size:40px` on all div.card like so:

```
div.card{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

As it is, when you remove the uncovered class, you also remove the font-size, so the change in font-size is causing that shifting. (Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/awm0ccbp/8/)